# scheduling backup in heroku command faills

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

According to the [heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#scheduling-backups), to schedule a pg backup you issue the command:

```
heroku pg:backups:schedule DATABASE_URL --at '02:00 America/Los_Angeles' --app sushi
```

This command doesn't seem to work for me and gives me the error:

```
Unexpected argument America/Los_Angeles
```

I tried with different time zones including the abbreviated ones like UTC.

Comment: Sorry, but were you able to get this working after all? I have exactly the same error.

Comment: If I remember correctlyI think I gave up on using a specific time zone and just used the default UTC and calculated the corresponding local value.

Answer (score 8):

To get this fixed in Windows you should use double quotes instead of singles quotes.

That would be:

`heroku pg:backups:schedule DATABASE_URL --at "02:00 America/Los_Angeles" --app sushi`

Comment: I'm on windows and this command not working:

'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Windows Git Bash

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could sounds odd but did you change the "sushi" for your app name? I just copy the command and used my app name and the backup is schedule.

[terminal heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcgvG.png)

Comment: yeap used my app name. Could you try with an app that does not exist? and see if you get the same error message?

Comment: it's returning "Couldn't find that app". Did specified some database?

Comment: i'll try with complete url

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be happening only on Windows. I had exactly the same problem on Windows 7 and was not able to solve it. However, when my friend executed the same command on Linux (for the same application), everything worked without any problems.

Comment: Happened on a macbook pro for me.